# Cannot enable server side includes in IIS5

Tags: html, windows-xp, iis-5, ssi

I am trying to enable server side includes in some plain html files. I need help enabling ssi via IIS on the localhost. I am running XP Pro, and using both ie8 and firefox to test the files.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it:

1. Open IIS admin on your local machine
2. Expand the local computer tree in the left pane (where it says COMPUTERNAME (local computer)
3. Under `Web Service Extensions` node, click `Server Side Includes` in the right window pane.
4. Right-click and select `Allow`.

There you go.

**EDIT:**

If you want to map a non-default (.shtml/.shtm) extension to SSI, you'll have to add it to your default site. You can do this by:

Right click your website in IIS, select `Properties`

Click the `Home` tab

Click the `Configuration...` button

Under the `Mappings` tab, click the `Add` button

The fields should be:

- Executable:  - C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll
- Extension: .whatever
- Verbs: Limit to GET,POST
- Script engine: checked
- Verify the file exists: checked

You'll have to try it out with .html files.. I'm not sure the consequences of mapping standard HTML files to work with SSI. I would think you're going to negatively impact performance as now IIS will treat all .html files as dynamic even when you aren't including them? Worth trying though I guess. An alternate solution would be to use the traditional .shtml/.shtm extensions..

Comment: Is this also going to set SSI for .html files as opposed to just .stm?